# Which entity class in Spring Boot should have cascade functionality?

Tags: spring-boot

I have an Employee entity class which has a one to many relationship with Skills entity class.

Should we specify cascade in Employee class or in Skills class to achieve the below mentioned conditions

- An entry in employee might not have an entry in skills
- An entry in employee might have  multiple entries in skills
- If we delete employee then the corresponding skills of the employee should also be deleted

Answer (score 0):

Map entities like below will fulfill the requirements.

In Employee entity :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="employee",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Skill> skills;
```

In Skill Entity :

```
@ManyToOne
private Employee employee;
```

*An entry in employee might have multiple entries in skills* -- **@OneToMany will do this.**

*If we delete employee then the corresponding skills of the employee should also be deleted*  --- **cascade all will do this**.